# How can I make my Champion Fighter more interesting?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounters

My group has been playing a swashbuckling campaign that plays out more like an episode of an adventure TV show than it does a dungeon crawl. As such my characters are involved in a handful of encounters per adventure and they enjoy frequent rests, so while my spellcasters always have spell slots to burn my Champion Fighter often finds herself with nothing more interesting to do than "I hit them with my cutlasses" every turn.

Rather than nerf my casters, I'm looking for any resources that might be able to provide my otherwise blunt instrument fighter with more that she can do.

Comment: Hi, Original Jigen, welcome to the site! Thanks for asking this question. If you have the time, take the [tour] to get some basic knowledge on how the site works, and a bronze badge along with it. About the question, I'm afraid it's too broad, as written, so I'm voting to put it on hold while we work out more specifics. "Resources for things my fighter can do" is too open-ended because there a _lot_ of things you can do/add/change. Can we possibly narrow it down? Have you talked to the player, for example?
 What does she want to be able to do?

Comment: @Michael It's too broad because it's asking for an open-ended list of what a GM can do to make things interesting for the champion fighter (it's also notable that we don't know what is "interesting" for the player). It can span everything from making combat less stab-it-until-it-dies, to giving the character levels of madness, just off the top of my head. If it were a player asking what he can do for his/her PC, maybe it's _possible_...?

Comment: @Michael Please [don't answer in comments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), which includes even partial answers or suggestions. If you want to answer, assist first in getting the question reopened (if it can happen at all), then post a proper answer using the answer feature.

Comment: What feats does this fighter have?  What level is this Champion?  What skills (Athletics, Intimidation, etc) does the fighter have?  This question lacks the detail necessary to assist in an improvement for the build of This Specific Fighter.  Please provide character details if you want to have any hope of this question getting re-opened.

Answer (score 10):

The Champion Fighter is literally designed to be the "I hit it with my sword" build. It gains not a single resource-based option over the entire course of it's 20 levels (beyond the ones that every Fighter gets, like Action Surge or Second Wind)

The easiest way to give a Fighter more options, is to rebuild it as a Battlemaster, who is designed to be the "I make a special attack" type. Additionally, the Battlemaster also has "recharge at rest" options, which means that, like your casters, they'll also be a little stronger in your campaign due to recharging their resources more often.

Alternatively, the DMG offers the "Gritty realism" (DMG 267) rest variant, where resting takes *much* longer. If you're noticing encounters being too easy (or too swingy) you might also check that out. It won't make a Champion Fighter more interesting, but it if you're experiencing other rest-related issues it might help.

Comment: Also, perhaps make more use of the maneuvers everyone can do -- shove and trip.

Answer (score 5):

If you are playing with [feats](http://dnd5nextcore.blogspot.de/p/feats.html) there could be some that help this pc feel special and give her options beside attacking with a cutlass.

*INSPIRING LEADER* is a feat that allows her to use a rallying speech to grant temp hp to your party, for example.

*MAGIC INITIATE* Allows her to learn 2 cantrips and one 1st level spell

*RITUAL CASTER* You learn to cast rituals. If she makes one of them summon familiar it can, from now on the familiar can use the help action for her attacks as well as scout for her.

These three are just examples.